# AFNetworking isConcurrent task how to resume or pause

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

When download is running and if at that time wifi will be `OFF` then I get downloading status `isConcurrent TRUE` and when wifi get `ON` then I get `isConcurrent FALSE`. My question is how do I pause or resume the downloading task when it is in concurrent state (internet goes off)?

Answer (score 1):

Store current task in a property and pause it when appropriate.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionDataTask *ongoingTask;


self.ongoingTask = [self.afhttpSessionManager GET:....];

//wi-fi is off

[self.ongoingTask suspend];

//wi-fi is on again

[self.ongoingTask resume];
```

Comment: Theb How to resume it?

Comment: By calling `[self.ongoingTask resume]`

Comment: I'm not using AFNetwork 2.0 I'm using older version of it